# Can I upgrade my Star Wars: Battlefront edition with Ultimate edition?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

I have a "normal only" Star Wars: Battlefront Edition (without any DLC) and I want to buy a season pass. But I have the opportunity to buy an **Ultimate Edition** in one store (because of a discount). If I buy this "Star Wars: Battlefront ULTIMATE edition" in store and I activate this game on my Origin account, do I get a season pass (or Upgrade to Ultimate edition) to my SW: Battlefront (normal edition)? Or do I get a message about duplicite of this game on my account?

Comment: Contact Origin support and ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already contacted the EA help desk. here is an asnwer:

> *You will have two versions of Battlefront in your Origin account - these will not conflict with one another.*